# extract elements from numpy array of arrays using list

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

This should be basic, but having been banging my head against a wall for a while now.

I have an array of arrays (16 x 16 of 128 x 128 sub-arrays), e.g.

```
a.shape

(16, 16, 128, 128)
```

I also have a list of indices of interest

```
print(indices)

[[2, 4], [3, 11], [6, 3], [9, 1], ......]
```

I want to extract the sub-arrays corresponding to the indices in the list. So, if pass the values of an individual index, this works properly, e.g.

```
b = a[2, 4]

print(b.shape)

(128, 128)
```

however, if I try and do this using my list indices, I do not get the same result:

```
b = a[[indices[0]]]

print(b.shape)

(2, 16, 128, 128)
```

I get a 2 x 16 array of the sub-arrays, which I do not want. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple workaround:

```
b = a[indices[0][0], indices[0][1]]
print(b.shape)
# (128, 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the two b are not the same. The first one is a[2,4] and the second one is a[[indices[0]]] = a[[[2,4]]] which in Python 3.6.9 will result in error. 
I guess for your result, a[indices[0]].shape = (2,16,128,128).